# Unity multiplayer build says no prefab attached but its attached

Tags: c#, networking, unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Hello we are trying to make a multiplayer unity game

We have network manager, network HUD, network identity on our player prefabs, and everything goes normal when we play the game from unity editor, but when we build and run the game it says there is not a player prefab attached to network manager.

We are sure that there is a prefab attached to it and as I said everything is ok when we run from the editor so what could be the problem here?

Comment: Have you perhaps attached the prefab from the scene into the player prefab of the Network manager?  Try dragging it from your prefabs in the folder window, to the player prefab slot. This is a big guess, as I'm mobile atm, and can't test things myself.

Comment: thanks for your suggest i just re-write the project and it works now.